# Better blog module than DNN's blog module

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Does anyone know of a much better blog module than the one that comes with DNN. We have found it VERY frustrating using the standard DNN module and need something that's going to be easier for our clients to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi check out digArticle from dignuke.com.  It's loaded with features and is very easy for end users. Especially when it comes to media management.

Comment: Thanks Mike, we've used digRotate in the past which was a bit resource intensive. We'll look into your digArticle if there's a trial and see how that runs. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I can also recommend the "News Articles" module from http://www.ventrian.com

It can not only handle news items but can be configured as a blog.

The level of customisation that is possible and community support available is fantastic and the module also has built in support for RSS import/export, bit.ly and gravatar.

I don't want this to sound like a sales pitch, but considering you can pick up all of Ventrian's modules for just $25 it is a real bargain!

I have used the same module to power the following pages - as you can see they all have different looks, but this is just through the creation of different templates:

- beta.neovoca.com/Ourblog.aspx - Module used as a blog
- beta.neovoca.com/Home.aspx -Blog posts pulled through to homepage
- beta.vomero.co.uk/Home.aspx - Homepage news slider showing latest articles
- beta.vomero.co.uk/News.aspx - Full list of news articles
- beta.vomero.co.uk/News/tabid/176/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/79/Red-Arrows-head-for-Torquay.aspx - Article view mode, with several attached pictures
- beta.vomero.co.uk/Guestcomments.aspx - Each guest comment is treated as an
  article and displayed in a jQuery accordion
- beta.vomero.co.uk/Accommodation/Vomero.aspx - Comments are also tagged - allowing them to appear on other pages across the site

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've actually been on that site but it seemed at the time that we could not download any kind of trial to test against another blog. I will keep this in mind though. Cheers!

Comment: I would just pay the $25 to get the module.  Even if you don't like the news articles module, one of the others there will be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [SunBlog](http://www.sunblognuke.com/) with our customers. Our requirements stressed customizability more than out-of-the-box simplicity, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good success with BlogEngine.NET you can read about it and get it from http://blogengine.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Ashley, I will keep this one in mind for clients who only want a blog in future. Unfortunately, because this is a DNN installation, it needs to be a module that plugs into DNN so that we don't have to integrate login details for two seperate systems and skin only one site. ;)

Comment: please also keep in mind that it is very easy to write an authentication extension for Blogengine.net, there are several examples out there. It's based on the .NET membership model.

The skinning issue is of course a fairly non trivial issue and I agree that it would be painful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ashley. I will run it by our guys here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[Efficion's Articles module](http://www.efficionconsulting.com/dotnetnuke/modules/articles.aspx) is great for blogging.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at SpeedBlog : http://dnnspeedblog.com/ it has some good features including spam protection which most others do not, as well as many other features such as templates, tags and threaded comments.  I think it's based on the standard DNN blog base so importing existing posts is meant to be easy.